# Reversing a number of infinitely many digits

Tags: infinity

Lets say we have a function that gets as input a real number and returns its reverse

e.g. 123.12 -> 21.321

So what happens when the input is a number *α* that has infinitely many digits.
Does then reverse(*α*) exist as a number? Is this number well defined?

Comment: how do you input a number with $\infty$ digits?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry π?

Comment: if you were to type $\pi$ in by hand, you would never finish. If you type $\dfrac{1}{7}$ into your computer, the computer would never finish. So you can't input a number with $\infty$ digits. Full stop.

Comment: you know, ratio of the circumference of a circle to its radius, roughly 22/7, starts 3.14159265358979323846....

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Well we can define a function that is f(x) = 2*x.
Then f(π) = 2*π. I talk in the same sense as this example.
Is the reverse(π) an actual number?That was my question

Comment: it would be infinite, because there are an infinite number of digits after the decimal point. Irrationals have no last digit.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry OK.Got it.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input is real numbers, then no. There is no real number which has an integral part with infinitely many digits.

But it's worse, do you map $\frac12$ to $5$ or the $\ldots9994$?

Comment: OK just saw about [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944284/can-a-number-have-infinitely-many-digits-before-the-decimal-point).
As for the second part isn't it 1/2 = 0.5 
reverse(0,5) = 50.I didn't get you on that part.

Comment: I thought that $0{.}5$ is reversed to $5{.}0$ which is equal to $5$ the last time I checked.

Comment: Ops sorry my mistake.It should be 5.0.
Can you elaborate on the ..9994?

Comment: Well, $\frac12=0{.}5=0{.}4999\ldots$. So which one do you take?

Comment: Thanks.One last thing you said if then input is real numbers then no.In which other set it may work? Will it be fine if the inputs were to be natural numbers?

Comment: Yes, if the input is a natural number the result is a rational number. You can always consider other systems like the $p$-adic numbers, or $10$-adic numbers which are slightly different but can be thought as infinite strings of digits, and so on. There's much much *much* more to mathematics than just the real numbers!

Answer (score 0):

There is an idea like that, called the $p$-adics.  The $p$ is because it works better when the base is prime instead of ten.